How would plate tectonics work in a shellworld?
For anyone not in the know, a shellworld is basically an artificial crust (or multiple layers of one) situated on top of some massive body, like a gas giant, a star or even a stellar fragment.  The one problem I see with shellworlds is that they are always anthro-elitist, exclusive strictly to Homo sapiens and their farm-bred plants and animals.  No wild species are allowed, let alone acceptable.  This is frustrating because for something as diverse as Earth, that is seeing the forest for the trees.  So let's add variety to that.  How do we do it?  By building one for the purpose of this brand-new subgenre of speculative evolution, the seedworld.
BlueSkinnedBeast of the Speculative Evolution Forum describes the subgenre in more detail than I'd ever hope to emulate:

Seedworlds are probably the commonest and most widespread of the
various genres of spec. They’re simple in concept, they look easier to
contemplate than the intricacies of trying to decide what lives and
dies in a classic future-evolution scenario or altered-KPg, they’re
relatively forgiving of outlandish or less-probable adaptations, and
they don’t have many moving parts to keep track of. It’s no wonder
that the genre includes many people’s first forays into speculative
evolution. It’s easy to look at something vast and famous like Serina
and think “I could do something like that, but with X organism
instead”.

This quote is merely to provide context.  The real question concerns plate tectonics.  In order for the creators' strategy to select Earth species to colonize a shell the diameter of Neptune and then leave for evolution to deal with them for hundreds of millions of years to come, this shell needs plate tectonics so that things will always keep on moving.  But how can plate tectonics be created on a shellworld and then established to function by themselves for hundreds of millions of years without human intervention?

Like the premise. Can we have some details of the shellworld, or is that something that should be developed in an answer?

VTC:Needs Details. You've tagged this question such that you're admitting it's an artificial construction, and yet you want us to answer from the perspective of natural evolutionary dependencies. A shell world must have an artificial structure that keeps the world from collapsing into the traditional spherical gravity well. That structure gets in the way of plate tectonics. And while we're ignoring it for the Q, I'm having trouble seeing past the necessity of the interior becoming a life-killing oven (life requires energy, which makes heat). (*Continued*)

If you are talking about super-size structures *(the one that instantly comes to mind is Ringworld), then there are no plate tectonics, simple distance does the job instead. RW is vast on a scale difficult to even imagine from ground-level.

... I'm all for the idea of having fun creating an imaginary shell world, but this is just another question asking us to crowbar science into magic. Why would any artificial construction want plate tectonics? Isn't it just another aesthetic considering the technological magic necessary to build the world and vent the heat in the first place? How do we ignore the problems of the shell theorem? How are we holding the inner surface to the outer surface in the first place?

@SoronelHaetir did well by bringing up ringworlds. Niven kinda (kinda, there aren't really plate tectonics on his ringworld) solve the problem because spinning the ring created the "gravity" (downward force) that held everything in place, but this causes erosion. He fixed that by pumping mass (dirt) to mountain tops (mostly on the ringworld walls, if I recall). But spinning a shell world doesn't solve enough problems. The further you go to the poles, the closer the "gravity" (downward force perpendicular to the surface) gets to zero.

@JBH  Because for a speculative evolution project spanning hundreds of millions of years, I need plate tectonics.  There's no other way around it.

@JohnWDailey Then use something other than an artificially constructed shellworld that requires structural support  and machinery for maintaining stability that gets in the way of plate tectonics. If being an engineer in the Real World has taught me anything, it's that every goal has unavoidable trade-offs and that one rarely gets their way.

It doesn't really make sense in-world as something the Shellmakers would do - at huge expense add Earthquake Machines to smash up their own delicate machinery? And I don't see how it fits your worldbuilding goal, to start with an alien megastructure and then assume away the things that make alien megastructures different from our own world.

@JBH  Are you suggesting that I just make up my own penny-per-thousand carbon copycat of Serina?

@ChristopherWells  I don't understand where you're going with that.

What I'm suggesting is that it's a bit of an effort to force upon a structure that cannot have what you want, what you want. You might as well ask how to have plate tectonics on the surface of a balloon - it would be just as realistic. You've selected a type of megastructure that cannot have what you want. A ringworld could - but you're stuck with zero-G at the poles, and that means your underlying magma will always become thinner and thinner as it seeps to the poles and excudes into the atmosphere, cooling. You need to choose another structure - after thinking each structure through.

@JBH  What do you mean, "cannot"?  Are you suggesting that we must limit ourselves strictly to convention?

Are you not asking for a realistic or science-based answer? If not, then you need to remove the [tag:megastructures], [tag:space-constructs] and [tag:technology] tags. You're asking because you want to address evolution. Just how much of this are we expected to treat as magic?

@JBH  None, because this was supposed to be for a speculative evolution project that spans hundreds of millions of years, not a novel that spans a few months at the very least.

You chose the tags, the conditions, and the topic. Let's throw all that to the wind. It's a hollow world with enough rotation to create 1G of force at the equatorial region. No structure getting in the way of magma and how the magma is heated is irrelevant. How does it work? We don't know, John. There's nothing to relate it to with one exception: concave motion is always more limited than convex motion. The bottom of a bowl is a very stable point.

I think you can have perfectly ordinary plate tectonics. Suppose your artificial construct is a massless ball. Dump perfectly ordinary material on it. Note that to have Earth-normal gravity the material will have a thickness equal to Earth's radius. Why would it not act like Earth does?

I'm not seeing a way around a "magic" answer. Yes, we could come up with a mechanism for guiding near-random plate tectonics, but at the end of the day, it would still have to be powered and enacted by force fields or some similar Clarkean magic.
You could ask what forces exist on a Neptune-like planet that could be translated into plate tectonics. Or how plate tectonics would work if little except the shell exists. Maybe you could rephrase it to specify what PT is giving you, and asking for options.

What is the purpose of the plate tectonics?  Is it to produce 'realistic' geography, or is it to periodically separate and/or join populations of lifeforms?  Is it something else?
